# suse linux ftp maximum number of files

Tags: linux, ftp

How do I change the maximum number of files allowed to be listed/transferred... on suse linux? both client and server are suse linux machines.

Comment: which ftp server you are useing?

Comment: @The Bndr: how do I find that out? the man page shows 'BSD General Commands Manual'

Comment: This question is better suited to serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never heard of an build-in mechanism to change the maximum number of listed files on an ftp deamon.

The maximum number of files, which are available by ftp, are depends on the underlying filesystem.
Also the standard BSD  FTP Server does not support something like an "maximum files" which are allowed to be transfered.

//Update: to tar the files into an cpmpressed archive use
tar cvzf tarfile.tar.z folder_to_archive
copy the file from one host to an other
scp tarfile.tar.z user@host:/path/
and open the tar again:
tar xvzf tarfile.tar.z

Comment: Hmm, you are right. The problem I'm facing is transferring some 10000+ files, Now I'm thinking I'll use ssh to tar the directory and scp the tarred file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Right use tar for example. it's also possible to compress scp connections see the update of my answer

Comment: @Rnet If you think, my answer could help you - please mark that answer as "right". ;-)  - Thank you :-)

Comment: I used ssh user@ip "cat files" > localfile, works like a charm :)